# SQL windows function partition by null values

Tags: sql, db2, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a data-set:

```
year     id
NULL     123
NULL     124
NULL     125
1932     126
1932     127
1933     128
1933     129
1934     130
```

I would like to create a running count, where I have the group of year with `NULL` values as one group and the other group with `non-null` values, namely.

```
year    count
NULL    3
1932    2
1933    4
1934    5
```

I have tried to do this by `union` of two `windows function` data set, namely:

```
select distinct year, 
count(id) over (order by year asc)
from data
where year is null

union

select distinct year, 
count(id) over (order by year asc)
from data
where year is not null;
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this such as:

```
select distinct year, 
count(id) over (partition by <whether year is null condition> order by year 
asc)
from data;
```

MY sql version is db2.

Comment: @DineshDB Please don't flag the OP to specifically "try" your updated answer.  All the answers below are valid, insofar that they generate the expected result set.

Comment: @DineshDB Yep, thanks! It works fine.

Comment: @Anthony, You are welcome..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(year INT, id INT)

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES( NULL,123)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(NULL,124)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(NULL,125)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(1932,126)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(1932,127)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(1933,128)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(1933,129)
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(1934,130)

SELECT D.year, MAX(D.RN)Count 
FROM(
    SELECT year,SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY CASE WHEN year IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY id) RN FROM @tab
    )D
GROUP BY D.year
```

**Output:**

```
year    Count
NULL    3
1932    2
1933    4
1934    5
```

Comment: The OP wants a running total.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, What do you mean by running total?

Comment: @Dinesh: Thanks! I guess a running total is like a cumulative. One for the null group and the other for the non null group.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Hope now it looks fine

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option which does not use analytic functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col,
    CASE WHEN t1.col IS NULL
         THEN
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data t2 WHERE t1.year IS NULL AND t2.year IS NULL)
         ELSE
         (SELECT COUNT(t2.id) FROM data t2
          WHERE t1.year = t2.year OR (t2.id <= t1.id AND t2.year IS NOT NULL)) 
    END cnt
FROM data t1;
```

Comment: Opps sorry for the misinformation, I am trying to create a running count instead. The question has been edited.

Comment: @Anthony I gave you an option uses correlated subqueries to compute the running total.  Perhaps not the most efficient solution, but it is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Union all will get your required output, its hard way to achieve this but yet would get output

```
declare @table table (year int, id int)
insert @table
(year,id)
select 
NULL  ,   123 union all
select NULL  ,   124 union all
select NULL   ,  125 union all
select 1932   ,  126 union all
select 1932   ,  127 union all
select 1933   ,  128 union all
select 1933   ,  129 union all
select 1934   ,  130


select Runningtotal, year from
(

select SUM(count) over (order by year) RunningTotal ,year from 
(
select count(*) count,year from @table group by year ) x
where year is not null

union all 

select SUM(count) over (order by year) Runningtotal ,year from 
(
select count(*) count,year from @table group by year ) x
where year is  null
) y  order by year
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 :

```
select distinct year, f3.NB                               
from tmpxx f1                                             
left outer join lateral                                   
(                                                         
  select count(*) NB from tmpxx f2                        
  where f1.year is null and f2.year is null or            
        f1.year>=f2.year                                  
) f3 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 2:

```
select distinct year,                                             
( select count(*) NB from tmpxx f2                                
  where f1.year is null and f2.year is null or f1.year>=f2.year   
) nb                                                              
from tmpxx f1
```